# How to add dependant libraries when creating an executable file from executable jar?

Tags: java, swing, deployment, launch4j

I created an executable jar (system.jar) which added lib folder.
How can you add the lib folder (contains `datepicker.jar`)  to  the `system.jar` when creating .exe file?

Using Launch4j and I wasn't able to add the lib folder.

Comment: You can use maven. Add your dependencies you want in the pom.xml file and then build it with <packaging>jar</packaging>, the finally generated .jar file will contain the 3rd party jars

Comment: Thank you..it was really helpful

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache Maven you can use [Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). This is explained in [Selecting Contents for Uber JAR](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) usage page.

Other build systems will have their own plugins e.g. there is [shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) for Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You can add required external jars from "classpath" tab in Launch4j.
In Main class select the executable jar (system.jar).
In class path add required jar i.e. lib\datepicker.jar

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).